# Problems in old URLs after migrating from IPB4 to XenForo 2

Tags: xenforo

I have done a migration for IPB4 to Xenforo 1, and then to Xenforo 2.
There is a script to redirect the old urls to the new: https://xenforo.com/community/resources/redirection-scripts-for-invision-forums-3-x.5948/
Are two files and this htaccess... I have done a lot of changes and nothing, no redirection for the old urls.

Example of old url: http://www.foroiphone.com/foros/tema/119668-iphone-7-7-plus-movistar-post-oficial/ that goes to can't find the page
New XF2 Url: http://www.foroiphone.com/threads/iphone-7-7-plus-movistar-post-oficial.119668/

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste your code instead of posting screenshots of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is:

```
#   Mod_security can interfere with uploading of content such as attachments. If you
#   cannot attach files, remove the "#" from the lines below.
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#   SecFilterEngine Off
#   SecFilterScanPOST Off
#</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On


    #   If you are having problems with the rewrite rules, remove the "#" from the
    #   line that begins "RewriteBase" below. You will also have to change the path
    #   of the rewrite to reflect the path to your XenForo installation.
    #RewriteBase /ip.board

    #   This line may be needed to enable WebDAV editing with PHP as a CGI.
    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # IPS Rewrite Rules
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(topic|forum|user)/ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)show(topic|forum|user)= [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/(topic|forum|user)/ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} ^/(topic|forum|user)/
    RewriteRule ^.*$ ips2xf.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^(data|js|styles|install) - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```